# CSS overlay on page with scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have made overlay for my page, but it has one problem, when you scroll down the page, contet you can see by scrolling scrollbar doesn't have overlay on it. Is it possible to prevent this anyway?

See example here, just scroll down and see what is the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/qXwTY/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the overlay div:

```
position: fixed;
```

Instead of absolute :)

Answer (score 5):

Set `.overlay { ... position:fixed;`

You can read this article to understand more css positionning: [*CSS Positioning 101*](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/)

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` not supported in old browsers specially IE 7. But you can do that through jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".overlay").css({"height":$(".contents").innerHeight() + 20 + "px"});
});
```

Comment: I just tried in IE7 and it worked with just CSS, I think it does work conditionally (not sure what the conditions are). IE6 was a no-go.